# Difference in behaviour?

Tags: grammar

Is this phrase correct to use 'Difference In behaviour' ?
For example, 'There is a lot of difference in behaviour between the two boys'

Comment: I would rather say *there isn't much difference* than *there is a lot of difference,* but I can think of no reason why *difference in behaviour* would be suspect. What leads you to think it might be?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *"a lot of"*, use some of the following adjectives to describe the difference:

- Big
- Considerable
- Dramatic
- Enormous
- Great
- Huge
- Large
- Major
- Profound
- Significant
- Real

As for the preposition, "in" works with "difference". It's OK to say "The difference in price is not very significant", so it should be correct to say "The difference in the boys' behaviour is significant".

Alternatively, you can say "There is a big difference between the the boys' behaviours" (note that usually "behaviour" is uncountable but in this case it is countable because we mean the way that a person behaves in a particular situation or under particular conditions ([the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/behaviour))).

Answer (score 0):

In https://qanda.typicalstudent.org/category/homework-help I find the following answer: it isnot orrect. I think it should be:
Two boys behave differently
...the differences between the boy`s behavior

Comment: I think you mean *between the boys' behaviors*